# Zf2 form hydrate entity's value which is not in db

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have an Entity which has one property which is boolean and it is not use as a database column. Examle

```
Entity {
    ..
    //other properties wich are @ORM/Column()...
    ...

    /** @var bool **/
    protected isSetSomething;

    getIsSetSomething(){...}

    setIsSetSomething(){...}
    ...
}
```

My prblem is when binding object i use ClassMethods hydrator

```
$this->setHydrator(new \Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods(false));
```

but unfortunately when trying to acces $object->getIsSetSomething() after form submition and binding the object - this value is not hydrated.

What hydrator should I set, or how to manage this?

Comment: You could try \DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject

Comment: This Hydrator is for properties managed by doctrine. Along the all porperties that are annotated for doctrine I have one propery $something that is just a boolean var which is not mentioned to be managed by doctrine and store in DB. Whatever Hydrator I tried to used, it never hydrate this value.